# Solr fle layout with dynamic fields

Tags: solr, pysolr

Im a newbie to SOLR and trying to understand dynamic fields,

Assume I have the following schema,

If document-1, contains 
id = 1, author = "Tom" , title = "Python", text = "Book", first_name_string = "Tom"and last_name_string = "Dan"

and If document-2, contains 
id = 2, author = "Brain" , title = "Java" , text = "Java"

How would the values be stored?

Is it my first document-1 and document-2 will be stored as seen above..What will be the values first_name_string and last_name_string for my document-2?

If I do a query on both the documents, how will the SOLR results look..

```
<?xml verson='1.0' ?>
<schema name='simple' version='1.1'>
  <types>
    <fieldtype name='string' class='solr.StrField' />
    <fieldType name='long' class='solr.TrieLongField' />
  </types>

  <fields>
    <field name='id' type='long' required='true' />
    <field name='author' type='string' multiValued='true' />
    <field name='title' type='string' />
    <field name='text' type='string' />
    <dynamicField name='*_string' type='string' 
      multiValued='true' indexed='true' stored='true' />
    <copyField source='*' dest='fullText' />
    <field name='fullText' type='string'multiValued='true' indexed='true' />
  </fields>

  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
  <defaultSearchField>fullText</defaultSearchField>
  <solrQueryParser defaultOperator='OR' />

</schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont provide data for any fields .solr will skip those fields for that doc.if you want to have all the fields in all the docs.please specify default for fields in your schema.